# How to get the PID of IRunningTask (Task Scheduler 2.0 library)

Tags: c#, .net, process, focus, scheduled-tasks

I started a task using `IRegisteredTask.Run()` and got `IRunningTask` object.

My Goal is to focus the main window of started task with `SetForegroundWindow` function.

First i want to know the PID (Process ID) of the running task.

There is `IRunningTask.EnginePID` property, but it gives me the PID of some `taskeng.exe` process (Task Scheduler Engine), this is not my task...

How to get the PID of IRunningTask?

Comment: Ultimately, a command line task launched using TASK_ACTION_EXEC could be represented by anything, like 3 processes for example. The Task Scheduler does not always have the notion of "what is" really the running task. You have more information about this than anything else because you know what you actually launched. Can't you use any other mean for this? If you assume you can do something interesting with the PID, than you must be able to enumerate processes by name or windows.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  The IRegisteredTask interface does not expose a PID property.

If you really need the PID, you might need to use the .Path and .Name properties of the IRegisteredTask and enumerate the currently running processes looking for a match.  When you locate the currently running process that has the same path and name as your IRegisteredTask, you can then retrieve the PID.  It's not pretty, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this method is that the task may have more than one instance simultaneously.

Comment: One thing you could do (and I have done this before) is to add a control to the main window of the task just for the purpose of carrying information you need.  For instance, add a TextBox to the window and set the Text of the control to some unique value (or the PID, or the HWND of the main form) for later use.  Then after you have located your app, use FindWindowEx to locate the Textbox and retrieve your information.  Yes, it's a hack.  Yes, there should be a better way.  However, yes, it will work.

Comment: User application running non-elevated while task running elevated, this method will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get it using IRunningTask.InstanceGuid (and then go through TaskScheduler.IRegisteredTaskCollection)?

--edited for completeness--

Since your final goal is to get the task itself, you can do that by using the unique GUID inside the engine's task collection.

Comment: my goal is finding the PID of the task i just started. How do i get it from IRegisteredTaskCollection?

Comment: Actually you don't (I don't if there is a way to, anyway). You only get the task itself.

Comment: Have you tried to add a ComHandler to the task? If your goal is actually getting the PID you can try getting the caller process ID in a handler or any other IAction and then map your tasks.